# Is testing generic collections for referential equality in C# a silly idea?

Tags: c#, collections, equality, fluent-assertions

I'm implementing a special case of an immutable dictionary, which for convenience implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Foo, Bar>>`. Operations that would ordinarily modify the dictionary should instead return a new instance.

So far so good. But when I try to write a fluent-style unit test for the class, I find that neither of the two fluent assertion libraries I've tried ([Should](https://github.com/erichexter/Should) and [Fluent Assertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/)) supports the `NotBeSameAs()` operation on objects that implement `IEnumerable` -- not unless you first cast them to `Object`.

When I first ran into this, with Should, I assumed that it was just a hole in the framework, but when I saw that Fluent Assertions had the same hole, it made my think that (since I'm a relative newcomer to C#) I might be missing something conceptual about C# collections -- the author of Should [implied as much](https://github.com/erichexter/Should/issues/1) when I filed an issue.

Obviously there are other ways to test this -- cast to `Object` and use `NotBeSameAs()`, just use `Object.ReferenceEquals`, whatever -- but if there's a good reason not to, I'd like to know what that is.

Comment: Have you looked at the MS immutable collections, btw? https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable

Comment: @JonSkeet Mmmm. What goodness you show us. Thanks.

Comment: Any type is an `Object`, why would you need to cast?

Comment: @Jodrell -- You need to cast it because the framework's implemented in terms of extension methods, and if you don't cast it, you get a more-specific extension method for `IEnumerable`, which unlike the less-specific one for `Object`, doesn't support the `NotBeSameAs()` operation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Looks awesome, but the license seems to prohibit using it in production code? (Also, my original question still stands -- I'd love to use the immutable collections for the internal implementation, but I'd still like the more limited wrapper object around them to implement IEnumerable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IEnumerable<T>` is not neccessarily a real object. `IEnumerable<T>` guarantees that you can enumerate through it's states. In simple cases you have a container class like a `List<T>` that is already materialized. Then you could compare both Lists' addresses. However, your `IEnumerable<T>` might also point to a sequence of commands, that will be executed once you enumerate. Basically a state machine:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetInts()
{
    yield return 10;
    yield return 20;
    yield return 30;
}
```

If you save this in a variable, you don't have a comparable object (everything is an object, so you do... but it's not meaningful):

```
var x = GetInts();
```

Your comparison only works for materialized ( `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` ) IEnumerables, because those state machines have been evaluated and their results been saved to a collection. So yes, the library actually makes sense, if you *know* you have materialized IEnumerables, you will need to make this knowledge public by casting them to Object and calling the desired function on this object "manually".

Answer (score 1):

In addition what Jon Skeet suggested take a look at this February 2013 MSDN article from Ted Neward:

[.NET Collections, Part 2: Working with C5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891057.aspx)

> **Immutable (Guarded) Collections**
>
> With the rise of functional concepts
> and programming styles, a lot of emphasis has swung to immutable data
> and immutable objects, largely because immutable objects offer a lot
> of benefits vis-à-vis concurrency and parallel programming, but also
> because many developers find immutable objects easier to understand
> and reason about. Corollary to that concept, then, follows the concept
> of immutable collections—the idea that regardless of whether the
> objects inside the collection are immutable, the collection itself is
> fixed and unable to change (add or remove) the elements in the
> collection. (Note: You can see a preview of immutable collections
> released on NuGet in the MSDN Base Class Library (BCL) blog at
> [bit.ly/12AXD78](http://bit.ly/12AXD78).)

It describes the use of an open  source library of collection goodness called C5.
Look at http://itu.dk/research/c5/

Comment: I took a look at C5, but I was having a lot of weird casting issues trying to get it to interoperate with `System.Collections.Generic`. (At some point if I get frustrated enough with the out-of-the-box collections maybe I'll give it another try and turn those issues into StackOverflow questions....)